# unable to resolve all dependencies in android studio after updating to 3.0.1

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

**I'm getting these errors:**

```
Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.

Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1.

Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1.

Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1.

Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.

Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12.

Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.

Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.

Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12.
```

**Application build.gradle file (project:MyApplication)**

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Application build.gradle file (Module:app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.hp_pc.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
core:3.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Have you try to clean & re build the code.

Comment: hello sir, all is working fine at my end. Here i am attaching screenshot for same. please do not downvote it.

Comment: @ankitpatidar you should add TEXT instead of IMAGE

Comment: @Amiya, i understand but i used same files so i think to attach scrrenshot for better understanding and clearance

Comment: @SriDatta Yalla, see my updated post

Comment: Is there any issues of proxy might cause this error? I'm using vpn over college internet connection.

Comment: problem solved.

Comment: I have turned off pshipon vpn that I'm using and went to File>invalid chaches/restart. every thing is fine after then.

Comment: Please ref my Answer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48171692/unable-to-resolve-all-dependencies-in-android-studio-3-0-1/51359061#51359061 
for same issue

Answer (score 0):

> Try this,
>
> Go to your

```
gradle.properties
```

> write the below code and Sync your project

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```

Comment: Try adding this -- in your gradle(Project) -->
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

You have to try like this

1. Delete your build folder in your project root directory
2. Delete your build folder inside of your project app folder

this both are cache some intermediate files and some debug-gable file so only its happening...

after delete this both folders then rebuild your project it will work properly.

follow this steps

[image]

your project root directory looking like that, here delete this highlighted build folder, then go to inside your app folder in this same window

inside app folder have one more build folder its also delete

then rebuild your project.

Comment: I'm new to android studio ,I didn't get what u have wrote. please tell me detail.

Comment: inside app folder i didn't find any build folder. but a gradle file is there as "build.gradle"

Comment: no problem, dont touch that build.gradle file. now just rebuild your project

Comment: Please ref answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48171692/unable-to-resolve-all-dependencies-in-android-studio-3-0-1/51359061#51359061 
which may help to get out of this issue

Answer (score 0):

Here i tried your gradle, here it is:

[image: Project level gradle]

[image: App Level gradle]

[image: Updated Android Studio]

what you are getting errors is not getting here.

My solution is:

1. Try to clear your project.
2. Go to *AndroidStudio* > *File* > *Invalidate/Restart*, it will help.
3. If nothing works then delete this project create new one.