# Unable to resolve all dependencies in android studio 3.0.1

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-developer-api

[Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPAFI.png)

Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0. Required by: project :app

```
No cached version of com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0 available for offline mode.
```

Error:Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.

```
Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0. Required by: project :app No cached version of com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0 available for offline mode. No cached version of com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0 available for offline mode. Could not resolve com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta3. Required by: project :app No cached version of com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta3 available for offline mode. No cached version of com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta3 available for offline mode. Could not resolve com.android.support:design:26.1.0. Required by: project :app No cached version of com.android.support:design:26.1.0 available for offline mode. No cached version of com.android.support:design:26.1.0 available for offline mode. Could not resolve com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0. Required by: project :app No cached version of com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0 available for offline mode. No cached version of com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0 available for offline mode. Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.4.2. Required by: project :app No cached version of com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.4.2 available for offline mode. No cached version of com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.4.2 available for offline mode. Could not resolve com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0. Required by: project :app No cached version of com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0 available for offline mode. No cached version of com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0 available for offline mode.
```

I want to make project offline.. if I dont have internet connection.. (For new project not connect to internet)

Comment: `No cached version of com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0 available for offline mode`, which says you definitely need to lower your version for appcompat else connect to an internet so that dependency will be downloaded

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue after updating AS to 3.1.3
Issues with me:

**I am getting these errors while syncing gradle**:-

Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve xxx.

Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve xxx.

Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve xxx.

Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve xxx.

Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve xxx.

**Solution for fix this issue**:

**1**. Check proxy in SDK Manager > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings>HTTP Proxy.
Auto-detect proxy settings should be checked.

**2**. Default settings Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle
Uncheck Offline work.

**3**. In left side panel select Project explorer > Android 
Check Gradel Scripts dir. look for cradle.properties (Global Properties)
It contains proxy added properties please do commented all of them.

**Try to clean and build.**

Now check all dependencies resolve.